# Intepretation of output from register. AT90E32 + stm32

Tags: stm32, atmel

i have a problem with documentation, which i don't understand. Documentation is here:
Read sequence is on the page 31.
I want to read Phase C voltage RMS.
From this register i get in that order: 0011110010001111.
Value read should be 233.3V.
I am beginner and really don't know hot to interpret this. When i read first byte from right 11110001 that is 241. The next byte read from left is: 00111100 which is 60, but when i multiply this by 0.01V (in documentation is that 1LSB should be multiply'ed by 0.01 - what means 1LSB? ) i get 241,6 V. That is correct? Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Documentation: https://pl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/Atmel-46003-SE-M90E32AS-Datasheet-1368788.pdf

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.